# How to Read desired string from a given text file ??? using C#

Tags: c#, file-io

In C#, Is it possible to read the desired string from a given text file ?

Sample content: 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbcccccc
dddddddddeeeeeeeeefffffff
gggghhhhhhhhiiiijjjjjjjkk
lllmmmmmmmmmmmnnnnnnnnnnn
ooooooooooopppppppppppppp

Now I have to read ffffff and iiiiiii and lllll and so on.... 
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

you need to see [**Regular Expression**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30wbz966(VS.71).aspx) Classes.

something similar, with modification will do

```
{([a-zA-Z])\1+)}
```

also check this resource

- [**http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

Answer (score 1):

If that is the exact string you are referring to, you could just enumerate the alphabet and use it as a regex e.g.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.IO;
...

char[] alpha = "abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToCharArray();
string contents = String.Empty;
using (var file = new StreamReader("MyFile.txt"))
{
     contents = file.ReadToEnd();
}

foreach (var c in alpha)
{
    Match m = new Regex(String.Format("{0}+", c.ToString()), RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Match(contents);
    if (m != null)
    {
        var str = m.Value;
        // do something with str
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see as m.Value here? And why would you create a regular expression matching a single char?

Comment: I forgot to add the + to the regex. It is so the OP can match the strings in the manner they have asked.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is regular expressions. Regular expressions are a powerful tool to search for specific patterns in strings. You can find much stuff about them on the internet, also have a look at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx).

Best Regards,
Oliver Hanappi